no carga el emsablado en mi servcio web al ejecutar
Amigos foreros me sale este error al ejecutar este servico web , marque la casilla para ejecucion en 32 bits, pero me sigue saliendo solo ala ejecutar.
que puedo hacer?

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! y esos errores??? probaste reiniciando?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
